# Centrar texto verticalmente en un DIV con flex + span style

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema en un div al centrar el texto verticalmente usando flex en el CSS. Al poner un span style, el texto contenido en el span salta a otra columna!

```css
.TEXT {height: 200px;
font-size: 20px;
text-align:center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<!--Ejemplo erróneo al usar span-->
<div class="TEXT">My name is<br>Daniel<br><span style=" font-weight:400; color:red;">From Spain</span></div>

<!--Así es como debería ir el texto-->
<div class="TEXT">My name is<br>Daniel<br>From Spain</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia la dirección del contenedor flexible a `column`:

```css
.text {
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* aquí */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!--Ejemplo erróneo al usar span-->
<div class="text">My name is<br>Daniel<br><span style="font-weight:400; color:red;">From Spain</span></div>

<!--Así es como debería ir el texto-->
<div class="text">My name is<br>Daniel<br>From Spain
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo que hace el desconocimiento!!!